# ICC from random effects model VS ANOVA

Tags: intraclass-correlation

ICC is talked about in the context of ANOVA as well as random effects model.

In case of the ANOVA approach, the calculation is defined as:

`MSB - MSW / ( MSB + (k-1) MSW)`

In case of random effects model, the calculation is defined as:

`Var(group) / (Var(group) + Var(subject)`

These two approaches seem to lead to totally different results. How are they related?